# What does flatten mean?

Tags: scala, flatten

I tried to understand the definition of `Some::flatten` and got into trouble. Here is how it looks:

```
def flatten[B](implicit ev: A <:< Option[B]): Option[B] =
  if (isEmpty) None else ev(this.get)
```

I didn't understand the mean of `A <:< Option[B]`. What does `<:<` mean?

Answer (score 6):

That is a generalized type constraint and it makes sure that the type you are flattening is of the form `Option[Option[T]]` (or `List[List[T]]`). What it does it removes one layer of `Option` or `List`. So `Some(Some(3))` becomes `Some(3)`, `Some(None)` becomes None, and `None` becomes `None`. For lists: `List(List(1,2), List(3))` becomes `List(1, 2, 3)`.

There is a very good article that describes the use of generalized type constraints in the standard library, found [here](http://blog.bruchez.name/2015/11/generalized-type-constraints-in-scala.html).

Edit: as @mavarazy noted, it also can flatten Seq[Option[T]] to Seq[T]. Generalized type constraints are a very powerful device that I consider one of the advanced features of the Scala type system.

Answer (score 5):

`A <: B` in general means that `A` is a subtype of `B`.

`A <:< B` in turn is something that provides an evidence of this subtype relationship, which essentially means that there is a way to turn an `A` into a `B`.

The function `flatten` is a member of the `Option[+A]` class, and it requires an

`implicit ev: A <:< Option[B]`

that is, some evidence that your type `A` can be turned into an `Option[B]`. Starting out from an `Option[A]` given this evidence, it can be turned into an `Option[Option[B]]`, which can then be smashed into a single `Option[B]`, as the other answers explain it.

Answer (score 3):

Flatten if you put it easy means - unwrap (simplify) input

In case of Option, it means if you have nullable of nullable, simplify to single level of nullable

```
Some(Some("a")).flatten = Some("a")
```

In case of Seq of Options, it means remove all nullables

```
Seq(Some("a"), None, Some("b")).flatten = Seq("a", "b")
```

In case of Seq of Seq, it means remove Seq level

```
Seq(Seq("a"), Seq(), Seq("b", "c")).flatten = Seq("a", "b", "c")
```

Comment: I read the question as asking not what `flatten` does,but what `A <:< Option[B]` means. And I'm not sure that "nullable" is what you mean there...

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul although the title "What does flatten mean?" sounds like he *does* ask what flatten does.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but the body of the question says otherwise.